# Как реализовать общение двух и больше компьютеров в java?

Tags: java, spring, сокет

как реализовать общение между двумя и больше компьютеров? Читал что нужно использовать сокеты, но возможно есть и другой вариант? Раньше делал только веб-приложения и с таким не сталкивался.

Суть заключается в том, что на каждом компе приложение будет обрабатывать информацию и передавать ее на "главный" комп. Можно это выполнить в spring, например?

Comment: Так-то технически веб-приложения тоже работают через те же самые сокеты, так что выбора-то и нет

Comment: А зачем другой вариант? Многие их использует и никто не жаловался.

Comment: используйте message Broker и облегчите себе жизнь

Answer (score 1):

Есть десятки способов в сотнях сочетаний. Начать стоит с изучения стандартных - RMI и JMS.

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать Vert.x для быстрого налаживания связи между машинами. Инструмент проще и сильнее, чем стандартный пакет java.net. 
Подробнее здесь: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/

Пример реализации сервера и клиента (для передачи сообщений используются дейтаграммы):

- Клиент - https://github.com/ikonyaev/vertxudpclient
- Сервер - https://github.com/ikonyaev/vertxudp